# Azure SQL: How to be notified if someone exports the database?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I run a system based around an Azure SQL Database.

A few different team members need to have read access to this database to perform support and management tasks.

However, I am concerned that by having access to the database, one of them may - with the best of intentions - export the database and manage the backup carelessly, resulting in a data breach.

How can I get Azure to notify me if somebody backs up the database (or downloads more than X million rows, maybe?) These people need to have database access, I would just like to know if they use it in a way that could cause a security risk for the platform.

Comment: what's the database role do they have? If they don't have the right permission,  the can't export the database or create the backup. Just for your concerns, If they have the permission to read or write the data in SQL database, we can't prevent the data breach.

Comment: they have permission to read the data. I know that means we can't prevent a data breach, but I'd like some sort of alerting that can flag when a suspicious event has happened such as reading an unreasonably large number of rows that might indicate an export

Comment: yeah, I can understand you. But for now, there isn't such a alert for the data exporting or large data downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/xevent-db-diff-from-svr) for this.

To set it up on Azure you can follow [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/extended-events-capture-step-by-step-walkthrough/ba-p/369013) tutorial.

For your case

1. You create a session
2. You Select the `rpc_completed` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/rpc-completed-event-class?view=sql-server-ver15)) event and click configure

[image: Select extended event]

3. In the `Global Fields` tab you can select the fields you want to keep track of. I.e.: Username, sql_text, session_id, database_name, client_*
4. In the `Filter` tab you can select a filter condition. In your case row_count would be appropriate.
   [image: Filter on row_count]

*When malicious users are smart, and retrieve small numbers of rows and page them this will go undetected. So a second filter could be Querys without WHERE clauses or a different approach based on your case.*

When extended events are setup to write to blobstorage. You would have a different process  (Azure Function, Runbook, ...) that would inspect the result and alert you.

*Extended events are moslty used for troubleshooting, they replace SQL profiler. So turning it on a production server may have a performance impact.*

Comment: This looks like a really smart solution, however as you say it does seem to be intended for debugging rather than for leaving it running 24/7 on a production server. How would you get the session to be permanently running, would it reliably stay running?

Comment: You can check a checkbox, start session on server startup. Extended events are build in to the engine, so they are very reliable, and the perfomance impact is way less than SQL Profiler.